# python3 in virtualenv yolk call causes IOError

Tags: linux, python-3.x, ubuntu-10.04, yolk

In ubuntu lucid I have `python 2.6.5` by default.I compiled `python3.3.1` and set up `virtualenv` and `wrapper` such that workon envpy331 gets me to work on python3.3.1.Then I installed yolk using `pip`

Now,when I run

```
>>yolk -l
```

it lists all python libraries installed even in python2.6.5 as below ,and finally throws an IOError

```
BeautifulSoup   - 3.0.7a       - active development (/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages)
Brlapi          - 0.5.4        - active development (/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6)
CouchDB         - 0.6          - active development (/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6)
Django          - 1.3.1        - active development (/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages)
Fabric          - 1.5.1        - active development (/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Fabric-1.5.1-py2.6.egg)
...
nose            - 1.3.0        - active development (/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages)
numpy           - 1.3.0        - active 
nvidia-common   - 0.0.0        - active 
oauth           - 1.0a         - active 
odict           - 1.3.2        - active development (/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/odict-1.3.2-py2.6.egg)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/yolk", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('yolk==0.4.3', 'console_scripts', 'yolk')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/yolk/cli.py", line 1090, in main
    my_yolk.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/yolk/cli.py", line 203, in run
    return getattr(self, action)()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/yolk/cli.py", line 223, in show_all
    return self.show_distributions("all")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/yolk/cli.py", line 298, in show_distributions
    metadata = get_metadata(dist)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/yolk/metadata.py", line 38, in get_metadata
    msg = email.message_from_string(dist.get_metadata('PKG-INFO'))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1488, in get_metadata
    f = open(self.path,'rU')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/onboard-0.0.0.egg-info'
```

Any idea why this happens? Do I need to compile python3 again and set up virtualenv?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer in a pull request on github

> This will let people and tools (e.g.: https://python3wos.appspot.com/) know that yolk is compatible with Python 3.
>   Should do a release to PyPI; it seems that the latest code in GitHub works with Python 3, but the last released version on PyPI (0.4.3; released 2012-02-06) doesn't work with Python 3.

so use the github release instead